# How to code an animation to run mutliple times in parallel in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, tkinter, parallel-processing

I am trying to wrap my head around parallel animations. 
In the following code, clicking on a square will cause a small animation. 
But declaring 2 boxes (or more) makes things more difficult: The animation called last will run and cause the other to pause and resume only after it is complete.
How to change my code so that all animation calls can run independently and in parallel?

```
#!python3

import tkinter as tk
import time

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # create a canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()

        # create a couple of movable objects
        self._create_token(100, 100, "green")
        self._create_token(200, 100, "black")

    def _create_token(self, x, y, color):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x-25, y-25, x+25, y+25, outline=color, fill=color, tags=color)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(color, "<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_token_press)

    def on_token_press(self,event):
        Rx = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
        x = 0
        y = 5
        for i in range(25):
            time.sleep(0.025)
            self.canvas.move(Rx, x, y)
            self.canvas.update()
        for i in range(25):
            time.sleep(0.025)
            self.canvas.move(Rx, x, -y)
            self.canvas.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do not use `sleep()` in tkinter. This will freeze the application. Use `after()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use blocking tasks in a GUI, they live inside an event loop that allows them to verify events such as keyboard, mouse, etc, if you use those tasks the GUI will probably freeze. what you should do is use `after()` for periodic tasks, in the following solution I have proposed to create a class that manages the animation in a simple way.

```
#!python3

import tkinter as tk
import time

class AbstractAnimation:
    def __init__(self, canvas, id_item, duration, _from = 0, _to = 1):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id_item = id_item
        self._progress = 0
        self._from = _from
        self._to = _to
        self.t = max(10, int(duration/(self._to -self._from)))

    def start(self):
        self.canvas.after(self.t, self.on_timeout)

    def on_timeout(self):
        if self._from <= self._progress < self._to:
            self.interpolated(self._from, self._to, self._progress)
            self._progress += 1
            self.canvas.after(self.t, self.on_timeout)

    def interpolated(self, _from, _to, _progress):
        pass

class Animation(AbstractAnimation):
    def interpolated(self, _from, _to, _progress):
        x, y = 0, 5
        if _progress < 25:
            self.canvas.move(self.id_item, x, y)
        else:
            self.canvas.move(self.id_item, x, -y)

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # create a canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()

        # create a couple of movable objects
        self._create_token(100, 100, "green")
        self._create_token(200, 100, "black")

    def _create_token(self, x, y, color):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x-25, y-25, x+25, y+25, outline=color, fill=color, tags=color)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(color, "<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_token_press)

    def on_token_press(self,event):
        Rx = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
        animation = Animation(self.canvas, Rx, 1250, 0, 50)
        animation.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation eyllanesc. I transformed my code to use the `after()` method.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mention is the comments and @eyllanesc also mentions in his answer, you generally shouldn't call `time.sleep()` in a `tkinter` program because doing so temporarily halts its `mainloop()` which essentially halts the running GUI for the duration. Instead you should use the universal [`after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method.

However, you don't really need to use to get delays to animation. Instead it can be used to periodically run an arbitrary function ***within*** the `mainloop()`, which provides the leverage to animate things if desired.

In the code below, this is done by first defining a `Token` class to encapsulate the values associated with one, and then creating a `list` of them named `_self._tokens`, and finally using `after()` to schedule moving all the items in it that are currently active. The function to be called by `after()` in this case is the `Example._update_tokens()` method.

Here's code showing how to implement this approach:

```
import tkinter as tk

UPDATE_RATE = 10  # Updates-per-second.
UPDATE_DELAY = 1000//UPDATE_RATE  # msec delay between updates.

class Token:
    WIDTH, HEIGHT, INCR = 25, 25, 1

    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y, color, max_value, dx, dy):
        self.canvas, self.x, self.y = canvas, x, y
        self.color, self.max_value, self.dx, self.dy = color, max_value, dx, dy
        self.value, self.moving, self.saved_direction = 0, 0, 1
        self.id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x-self.WIDTH, y-self.HEIGHT,
                                               x+self.WIDTH, y+self.HEIGHT,
                                               outline=color, fill=color)
        self.canvas.tag_bind(self.id, "<ButtonPress-1>", self._toggle)

    def _toggle(self, _event):
        """ Start movement of object if it's paused otherwise reverse its
            direction.
        """
        if self.moving:
            self.moving = -self.moving  # Reverse movement.
        else:  # Start it moving.
            self.moving = self.saved_direction

    def start(self):
        self.moving = self.saved_direction

    def pause(self):
        if self.moving:
            self.saved_direction = self.moving
            self.moving = 0


class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()

        # Create list of movable objects.
        self._tokens = []
        self._tokens.append(Token(self.canvas, 100, 100, "green", 25, 0, 5))
        self._tokens.append(Token(self.canvas, 200, 100, "black", 25, 0, 5))

        tk.Button(self, text='Go', command=self._start_paused_tokens).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
        tk.Button(self, text='Pause', command=self._pause_tokens).pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        # Start the updating of active objects in _tokens list.
        self.after(UPDATE_DELAY, self._update_tokens)

    def _start_paused_tokens(self):
        """ Start any paused Tokens. """
        for token in self._tokens:
            if token.moving == 0:
                token.start()

    def _pause_tokens(self):
        """ Stop any moving Tokens. """
        for token in self._tokens:
            if token.moving != 0:
                token.pause()

    def _update_tokens(self):
        """ Update any objects in Tokens lst that aren't paused. """
        for token in self._tokens:
            if token.moving > 0:
                if token.value < token.max_value:
                    token.value += token.INCR
                    token.canvas.move(token.id, token.dx, token.dy)
                else:
                    token.value = token.max_value
                    token.moving = -token.moving  # Reverse moving.
                    token.canvas.move(token.id, token.dx, -token.dy)
            elif token.moving < 0:
                if token.value > 0:
                    token.value -= token.INCR
                    token.canvas.move(token.id, token.dx, -token.dy)
                else:
                    token.value = 0
                    token.moving = -token.moving  # Reverse moving.
                    token.canvas.move(token.id, token.dx, token.dy)

        self.after(UPDATE_DELAY, self._update_tokens)  # Continue doing updates.

    def on_token_press(self, event):
        closest_token = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)
        dx, dy = 0, 5
        for i in range(25):
            time.sleep(0.025)
            self.canvas.move(closest_token, dx, dy)
            self.canvas.update()
        for i in range(25):
            time.sleep(0.025)
            self.canvas.move(closest_token, dx, -dy)
            self.canvas.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks Martineau. That's wow! a bit complex for me though I think I understand what you mean and the purpose of the encapsulation. I am going to remove all the `time.sleep(XX)` from my code and use after and encapsulation.

Comment: Glad to hear you think it may help. Encapsulating as much as possible in the `Token` class is often a good way of dealing with the extra complexity because it moves a lot of the code and logic dealing with each instance's internal data into class methods and out of the main program. It will also allow you to derive separate subclasses that specialize the base classes more generic behavior as needed and without repeating it. An example of the might be create one to represent tokens that have a different shape.